# Adding a heading row in a table using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

In my solution the data is fetched from database and displays in a table. I want to add heading as Phase 1 and Phase 2 to separate the rows belonging to each phase.

Currently table looks like :

```
Week      Project       OS      TotalTests        #cycle 
    1        P1        Windows     0                 0
             P2       Linux,UFO   4799               1
    1        P4       Android      10                10
```

I want the table to be something like:

```
Week      Project       OS      TotalTests        #cycle 
                           Phase 1
     1        P1        Windows     0                 0
              P2       Linux,UFO   4799               1

                           Phase 2
     1        P4       Android      10                10
```

Code:
data.Phase is the field which contains values 1 & 2 in db. Please any help?

```
        let rows=[], nrows=data.length;

        if (nrows > 0) {

            let ww=data[0].WW, totalTests=0, totalCycles=0;

            for (var i=0; i<nrows; i++) {

                let row = '<tr>' +
                          '<td>' + 'WW- ' + data[i].WW + '</td>' +
                          '<td>' + data[i].Project + '</td>' +
                          '<td>' + data[i].OS + '</td>' +
                          '<td>' + data[i].TotalTests + '</td>' +
                          '<td>' + data[i].Run + '</td>' +
                          '</tr>';
                totalTests += parseInt(data[i].TotalTests);
                totalCycles += parseInt(data[i].Run);
                rows.push(row);

                if ( ( data[i+1] && (data[i+1].WW != ww) ) || !data[i+1] )  {
                    rows.push('<tr class="totals"><td colspan="3">Total</td><td>' + totalTests + '</td><td>' + totalCycles + '</td></tr>');
                    ww = data[i+1] ? data[i+1].WW : '';
                    totalTests = 0;
                    totalCycles = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            rows = ['<tr><th colspan="5" style="text-align:center">No Data to display</th></tr>'];
        }

        $('table#GraphTable tbody').html(rows.join(''));

        // Create week rowspans.
        $('table#GraphTable tbody tr.totals').each(function() {
            var $weekRows = $(this).prevUntil('tr.totals');
            $weekRows.last().find('td').first().attr('rowspan',$weekRows.length);
            $weekRows.not(':last').each(function() {
                $(this).children('td').first().remove();
            });
        });
    }
})
```

Comment: Share your `data`

Comment: How do you know which phase it is? Is there a row in the database that points it? Please share the final value of the `data` variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before Starting of the loops you can do something like below

```
let header1Row = "";
let header2Row = "";
let header1Row = '<tr><td colspan="5" style="text-align:center">Phase 1</td></tr>';
rows.push(header1Row);

// Meanwhile in the loop check for the phase value
// if it is 2
if (header2Row === "") {
  let header2Row = '<tr><td colspan="5" style="text-align:center">Phase 2</td>/tr>';
  rows.push(header2Row);
}

// the above loop will run only one time
```

Comment: but what about Phase 2? this wil come after some rows when in db Phase value is "2"

Comment: this logic helped.Thanks :)